# Error getting document: TypeError: Cannot set property 'userexist' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase

In my angular firebase project, I have defined a global variable `userexist`. This variable is called in function `searchUser()`. but when it is called, there is a error happen as `Error getting document: TypeError: Cannot set property 'userexist' of undefined`... Could you please help to fix the problem?

```
export class AddnewComponent implements OnInit {

  userexist: boolean = false;
...
  searchUser(value) {
      var userId = value.email;
      console.log("user ID is:" + userId);
      this.userDoc = this.afs.doc('users/'+ userId);
      this.afs.doc('users/'+ userId).ref.get().then(function(doc){
        if (doc.exists) {
            console.log("Document data:", doc.data());
            this.userexist = true;
        } else {
            console.log("No such document!");
        }
      }).catch(function(error) {
            console.log("Error getting document:", error);
      });
  }

...
```

Comment: _"I have defined a global variable userexist"_ Note that is not a global variable, it is a class property

Comment: Replace `function (doc) { ... }` with `(doc) => { ... }`.

Comment: Hi ConnorsFan, many thanks. It works! Could you please tell me the differences between these two syntax... To me, they seem the same.

Comment: You can take a look at [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#No_separate_this) about arrow functions. The answers to the [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback) also give a lot of details about `this` in callback functions.